# Binary representation of a 32 bits integer

Tags: java

I have writen a very simple algorithm for generating the binary representation of a 32 bits integer.

Here is my code:

```
public class NumberManipulator {

public static final int HEAVIEST_BIT = 32;


public static long intPower(int value, int power) {
    if (0== power) {
        return 1;
    }

    long result = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i <= power; i++) {
        result = result * value;
    }
    return result;
}


public static void main(String[] args) {

    int n1 = 7;
    int n2 = 18;
    int n3 = 65;
    int n4 = 11;

    System.out.println(getBinaryRepresentationOf(n1));
    System.out.println(getBinaryRepresentationOf(n2));
    System.out.println(getBinaryRepresentationOf(n3));
    System.out.println(getBinaryRepresentationOf(n4));

}

public static String getBinaryRepresentationOf(int number) {
    StringBuilder resultBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i =  HEAVIEST_BIT-1;  i >= 0; i--) {

        long checker = (number >> i) & 1; // (number & intPower(2,i));    (number >> i) & 1; 
        if (checker == 1 ) {
            resultBuilder.append("1");
        } else {
            resultBuilder.append("0");
        }
    }
    return resultBuilder.toString();
}
```

This code is working fine. The following image illustrate the call to the main's method results.

[image: Binary representation of 32 bits numbers]

I am however facing an issue when I change `long checker = (number >> i) & 1`by `(number & intPower(2,i))`, it simply gives me aberrant results and I really can't figure out why. Any help regarding this is very welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imagine `number` is 2. In binary it's `0010` and you're comparing with `intPower(2, 1)`. What you're doing is `2 & 2` (`0010 & 0010`), result is `2` again (`0010`).Your if will fail because it compares with `1`. In short what you get after `&` is `0` or *rhs* value (not always `1`/`0` like with `(number >> i) & 1`).

Change your code to:

```
if (checker != 0) {
    resultBuilder.append("1");
} else {
    resultBuilder.append("0");
}
```